# Can a php If/else function cause a increase in CPU usage?

Tags: php, cpu

I have let's say around 20,000 products on my website

And for every product and page to run this

```
if ($price == "0" ) {
  $text_price = "Call us ";
  $price = "for a price.";
  echo $text_price;
  echo $price;
}
else{
  echo $text_price;
  echo $price;
}
```

I have this code in around 5 different files for
Product page,
Manufacturer page,
Category page and so on.

Could this get the CPU usage high in the sky? The site has around 800 sessions a day according to google analytics.

Comment: Rule #1 `If it ain't broke, don't fix it.` :)

Comment: Rule #2 `Optimise where you can`

Comment: we have [Codereview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) for that!

Comment: Well... it will cause *more* CPU usage than if that statement wasn't there. However, it is soooo trivial that you will hardly see any difference. If in doubt (or generally *always*): **benchmark** to figure it out.

Comment: @Viral This would not be a good question for CR. This is just a small example piece of code, nothing that CR can do with this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wouldn't have thought it would have that much of an impact (800 a day isn't that much). Although I would write it like this.

```
if ($price == '0' ) {
  $text_price = 'Call us ';
  $price = 'for a price.';
}

echo $text_price;
echo $price;
```

there's no need to put the echo inside the `if` as it'll execute anyway afterwards.  Single quotes mean that the string isn't parsed twice by the compiler.